# Is there an equivalent for closure relation for spherical Bessel function for the 6th power of $x$?

Tags: spherical-harmonics, special-functions

I am aware of the the closure relation for spherical Bessel functions
$$
\int_0^\infty{dx\; x^2 \; j_l(k_1x)j_l(k_2x)} = \frac{\pi}{2k^2} \delta(k_1 - k_2)
$$
as well as the orthogonality relation.
I would love to know if it is possible to solve integrals with higher powers of $x$. Specifically, what is the solution of
$$
\int_0^\infty{dx\; x^6 \; j_l(k_1x)j_l(k_2x)} .
$$
I found a recursion relation in a paper from 2017 but the resulting expression is insanly complex. I'm afraid I'm pretty clueless in this area... Sorry.

Comment: Have you looked in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik? If they don't have it, then Prudnikov would be my next stop.

Comment: The natural relation would be not be for spherical Bessel functions but for hyper-hyper-hyper-hyper-spherical Bessel functions.